# axios проблема с временем запроса

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

на фронте делается запрос на бэк, запрос может длится 10 минут. Но через некоторое время на фронте выкидывает ошибку, в то время как на бэке еще данные обрабатываются.
Каогда на бэке все обработалось, можно перезагрузить страницу и все норм. Это из-за длительного времени запроса? Как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю запрос отваливается изза таймаута, нужно как-то увеличить время ожидания

Comment: Мммм, всмотрелся, проблема в сервере, от обрывает соединение скорее всего